# Seeding DB made by Code First EF Core DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am wondering what is the best way to generate required data right after EF Core has made the database.

I see that people make classes in the C# code to do it but how about if you got alot of data? For me I got to import all States from the US in my system.

I would think it would be better to run some sort of sql script to do this, but I guess some check would be needed for duplicates.

Edit

Say I want to use these scripts that I found in my database. So when my database is auto generated when my project runs for the first time they get populated.

https://github.com/hiiamrohit/Countries-States-Cities-database

Comment: I don't see US states as being "a lot of data"; are you talking about just the state names?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils - It will become more and more, as I am thinking of adding other countries and their states as well.

Comment: You could then look at this as a data set that you need varying levels of detail. IOW, why not just populate, or use a population of, data that provides all that is available and filter out what you need now? This data is generally static.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using EF Core 2.1 they have actually added a new feature that is very nice.

[EF Core 2.1 Release Announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/05/30/announcing-entity-framework-core-2-1/)

In your `OnModelCreating` method of your DbContext you now have an HasData extension method on the Entity method.

Here are two examples:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().HasData(new Blog {BlogId = 1, Url = "http://sample.com"});

modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasData(
    new {BlogId = 1, PostId = 1, Title = "First post", Content = "Test 1"},
    new {BlogId = 1, PostId = 2, Title = "Second post", Content = "Test 2"});
```

Comment: That is handy but I just don't want to manually write hundreds of lines of data in my C# code when there exists scripts of for countries/states. Though maybe in the end it is best not to mix and just have to painfully add it myself as if I am going to be adding say customers who are associated to those countries then I won't have access to the reference if I created it via a script

Answer (score 0):

To generate a lot of data, you can use a lib like [Bogus](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus) which is "is fundamentally a C# port of faker.js and inspired by FluentValidation's syntax sugar". We use it in our project and it fits perfect. You can generate real name, real countries, real phone numbers etc.
An example from GitHub:

```
var testUsers = new Faker<User>()
    .CustomInstantiator(f => new User(userIds++, f.Random.Replace("###-##-####")))
    .RuleFor(u => u.Gender, f => f.PickRandom<Gender>())
    .RuleFor(u => u.FirstName, (f, u) => f.Name.FirstName(u.Gender))
    .RuleFor(u => u.LastName, (f, u) => f.Name.LastName(u.Gender))
    .RuleFor(u => u.Avatar, f => f.Internet.Avatar())
    .RuleFor(u => u.UserName, (f, u) => f.Internet.UserName(u.FirstName, u.LastName))
    .RuleFor(u => u.Email, (f, u) => f.Internet.Email(u.FirstName, u.LastName))
    .RuleFor(u => u.SomethingUnique, f => $"Value {f.UniqueIndex}")
    .RuleFor(u => u.CartId, f => Guid.NewGuid())
    .RuleFor(u => u.FullName, (f, u) => u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName)
    .RuleFor(u => u.Orders, f => testOrders.Generate(3).ToList())
    .FinishWith((f, u) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User Created! Id={0}", u.Id);
        });

var user = testUsers.Generate(10000); // Generated 10000 users that match rules
```

Comment: I am going to check out Bogus for populating developer DBs...thank you

Comment: I am not looking ot make fake data(though this can be helpful later). I am looking at the requirements where I want to store all the countries and their states/provinces in tablles so I can reference them later on. I am asking what the best way to get this data is in.

Comment: @chobo2, I don't believe this data needs to be faked; the data is well-defined. If it's not readily available through an API, you can populate this data *once* for all scenarios.

Comment: So your asking where to find this data and how to populate them? Sorry, but this depends on your particular domain. It could be available in the intertnet, there could be a public available JSON file, but theese are just assumptions - you just have to make a research for your particular case. If you find JSON file, you can write some code, that inserts data into your DB. But still, you will need to write some kind of Adapter to adapt to their structure. We cant help you any more than that.